# Python stacked dictionary with multiple values per combination of multiple keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

So I have a CSV, which is then transformed into a dataframe and it's content it split in columns, based on a delimiter.

```
to_test_df = pd.DataFrame(Output)
test = to_test_df[0].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

The rows look as follows (snip out of the CSV, for a better view)
[image]

I have created afterwards a dictionary, in which I would like to have the data appended.

```
results = {'Column1':[],'Column2':[], 'Column3':[], 'Column4':[], 'Column5':[], 'Column6':[], 'Column7':[],
           'Column8':[], 'Column9':[], 'Column22':[], 'Column10':[], 'Column11':[], 'Measure_description':[],
           'Measure_value':[]}
```

Now, what I would like to do is to append the data from my dataframe within the dictionary.
The thing is that starting with column 12, all the Even numbers should be added within the Measure_description Column and all the Odd numbers should be added within the Measure_value column.

```
for i,j in test.iterrows():
    results["Column1"].append(j[0])
    results["Column2"].append(j[1])
    results["Column3"].append(j[2])
    results["Column4"].append(j[3])
    results["Column5"].append(j[4])
    results["Column6"].append(j[5])
    results["Column7"].append(j[6])
    results["Column8"].append(j[7])
    results["Column9"].append(j[8])
    results["Column22"].append(j[9])
    results["Column10"].append(j[10])
    results["Column11"].append(j[11])
    results["Measure_description"].append(j[AllTheEvenNumbersAfter12]) 
    results["Measure_value"].append(j[AllTheOddNumbersAfter12])
```

The problem is that when I am using the append, I am overwritting the previous value and I get to have the last 2 columns added to the dict:
[image]

Instead of having: (which is basically the desired output)
[image]

What can I do to reach the desired output?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does the even and odd value is fixed in certain columns?

Comment: You can convert a DataFrame to a dictionary directly, without looping. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: Any reason you are not reading the csv directly into a dataframe instead of reading then splitting? Also, could you please include sample csv data. The end result needed is another dataframe with the 12th+ columns combined according to even, odd? Is it ok to merge these  columns in a single row instead of creating multiple rows for each column?